# Unable to translate "The following tasks were handled incorrectly:" on review suspension page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, review-suspension

There is no sentence to translate *"The following tasks were handled incorrectly:"* on the [review suspension page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/review/suspensions/historical):

> [image]