# Translation is not used for robo-review description

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, review-suspension

[Translation for robo-review](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15706) on review suspension page doesn't used for some reason:

> [image]

Related: [Unable to translate "The following tasks were handled incorrectly:" on review suspension page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394068/339911)